# Angular 2 Firebase Hosting appears to require the hash marking

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

How can I configure a normal URL for my routes using Angular 2 and Firebase Hosting?

example route:
https://mywebsite.com/privacy-policy

I tried loading my site to Firebase hosting with routes defined this way, but I could not navigate to my routes.

My workaround was to introduce the hash mark strategy for routes something like the following-

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
            .....
            {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
        ])
    ],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, ...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup your firebase project to forward every request to your index.html.

During `firebase init` you got asked if you want to redirect all requests, maybe you answered with no..

add this to your `firebase.json`

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: By what magic did you know this was my problem!?!?!  Thanks so much.